# Partner Users - Tasks assignment and visibility

Tags: sharing, tasks, activities, partner-communities, visibility

As i have seen by default, when a partner user creates a Task and assigns it to a queue/group, this task is not visible to that user.

Requirements:

1st Requirement:
When a partner user assigns a task to a group/queue, he should be able to view this Task. How can i achieve the following?

2nd Requirement:
When a partner user assigns a task to a group/queue, all users under the Account of current user to be able to view this Task. Example: I have a partner account with two contacts (A and B), and those two contacts have been enabled as partner users. If user A creates a Task and assign it to a group/queue (e.g Financing Team), users A and B should be able to view this Task.

How can i achieve those two requirements?

Comment: Whats the license the partner user is on? in the past i have seen certain community licenses wont allow you to use apex sharing

Comment: License is "Partner Community"

Answer (score 0):

For the first requirement, one of the approach can be create a apex sharing as soon as a task is assigned to a group or queue.

For the second requirement you can create sharing sets on the community.
Go to digital experience setting then sharing set. By using sharing set you can easily share all the record with the user falling under same account.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this will work

Comment: Hello prajawal and thank you for your response. Is it possible to create Apex sharing on task object? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Also, the same seems to happen with Sharing sets. I don't see the Task object on sharing sets available.